# How to store and deal with big chuncks of text between Javascript and HTML

Tags: javascript, html, text

So , I'm using HTML , css and JavaScript, I did a form , where the user will give different data, like name , adress , ID number , etc and I want to introduce those values into a preformatted text  (like a renting contract)... Should be easy , right?

***What I did :***

1 - I have created an HTML form which will take in info from the user , like name, adress , etc

2 - I will store the data provided into JavaScript variables.

```
let ProprietarioName;
let ArrendatarioName;
let Duracao;

function UpdateVariables()
{
    Proprietario = document.getElementById("ProprietarioNome").value;
    Arrendatario = document.getElementById("ArrendatarioNome").value;
    Duracao = document.getElementById("Duracao").value;
    console.log(Proprietario);
    console.log(Arrendatario);
    console.log(Duracao);
}
```

3 - Introduce the variables within the location desired of the text.

***What I want to know :***

4 - The text is quite long , I dont know where to save it or how. How should I handle a big text like that of a contract , if I can't save it to a variable or an array or ... I don't know, something!

5 - Where should I save that text (let's say ipssum lorem) so that then I can introduce the variable inside that text? Into the HTML file or the JavaScript file ?

This is a very noobs question , sorry.

Comment: You can save the text inside a .txt file, and wherever the input should be placed you can write in that .txt file something like `((input1))` (as text). Then read the text file with JS into a variable, and use `replace()` to replace the temporary text with the inputs

Answer (score 0):

Two ideas:

1. Save in hidden textarea tags

```
<textarea id="ProprietarioNome" style="display: none;"></textarea>
```

2. Save data to local storage. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage . The advantage over local storage is that it persists when pages are reloaded.